Scikit Learn Random Halving Search CV
So, I am attempting to use 'HalvingRandomSearchCV' on some classification data with 5 classes of possible outputs. My training data is of shape (x, height, width, channels) and my labels are of (x, 5) in the one-hot style. However, when I try and use 'fit' on the initialized HalvingRandomSearchCV it throws the error:
**'ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (x, 5) instead.'**
I am not sure where to go from here, as my data and parameters work with RandomSearchCV but not with this. And according to the documentation, y can either have a shape of (n_samples,) (like what it is requesting here) or (n_samples, n_outputs) (what I am trying to do)
My initialization line: random_search = HalvingRandomSearchCV(estimator=themodel, factor=3, param_distributions=search_space, cv=cv, scoring=score, min_resources='smallest')
I tried to change min resources, and look up some guides online, however all the data being used is mostly unsupervised or generated by the make classification in scikit learn which is hard to decypher. Other that that, I have no idea where to start.

Always provide the full error traceback, and ideally a [mre] (a small example dataset and minimal code leading to the error).
